# Swift multiple values being saved to coredata

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm making a game that has a few constants that are in it:

```
struct moneyConstants {
    static var tapValue = NSInteger()
    static var tapMultiplier = NSInteger()
    static var moneyPerSecond = NSInteger()
    static var money = NSInteger()
}
```

I'm using CoreData to save the values after when the application closes. I want to know if you are able to save multiple values at once. Lets say my code to save something is:

let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

```
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Constants", inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

    let moneyS = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

    moneyS.setValue(moneyConstants.money, forKey: "moneySave")

    do {
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
```

If I wanted to save a second value like:

```
let moneyPerSecondS = NSManagedObject(entity:entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
moneyPerSecondS.setValue(moneyConstants.moneyPerSecond, forKey: "money")
```

Can I place those lines before the `do {` section? Or do I have to put it after the `do {` section and then write another `do {` section?

Comment: I guess this is not possible.But not sure

Comment: you can always do this but.( moneyS.setValue(moneyConstants.moneyPerSecond, forKey: "money"))

Comment: Not related, why do you use `NSInteger()` rather than native `Int` e.g. just `static var tapValue = 0` ? And struct and class names are supposed to start with a capital letter.

Comment: @vadian I used NSInteger() because if I don't then i can't save the values into coredata. Or can I? I haven't used coredata alot.

Comment: Then use `Int32` : `static var tapValue : Int32 = 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can (if the attributes are declared in the model):

```
let moneyS = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

moneyS.setValue(moneyConstants.money, forKey: "moneySave")
moneyS.setValue(moneyConstants.moneyPerSecond, forKey: "money")
```

Everything which does not `throw` is not required to be placed in a `do` scope.